# C# SQL server stored procedure Angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, sql-server, stored-procedures

In the following sample of code, I am trying to get data via C# and give it in front-end via Angular..To be more specific, I want to pass a value in stored procedure and get back 4 elements.. The value I am passing is coming from URL via Angular(state provider)

**c# controller:**

```
public ActionResult NewEventDetails(SelectEventDetailsDTO payload)
{
    var neweventDetails = _eventItemManager.NewEventDetails(payload);
        return neweventDetails.GetSuccess();}
```

**event manager (another c# controller):**

```
public EventDetails NewEventDetails(SelectEventDetailsDTO payload)
{
    var itemID = payload.itemID;
    var it = new Item(itemID);
    it.LoadItemNew(itemID);
    return null;
}
```

**DTO class:**

```
   public class SelectEventDetailsDTO
    {
        public int itemID { get; set; }
         public string itemName { get; set; }
        public string itemLocation { get; set; }
        public string itemChBy { get; set; }
     }
```

**The final collector that calls the procedure:**

```
public string LoadItemNew(int ItemID)
{
    var acf = new AcFunctions();
    var newstorevalue = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(acf.AcConn(), "sp_lightItem", ItemID);
    ItemLocation = Convert.ToString(newstorevalue.Tables[0].Rows[0]["itemLocation"]);
    ItemName = Convert.ToString(newstorevalue.Tables[0].Rows[0]["itemName"]);
    ItemChBy = Convert.ToString(newstorevalue.Tables[0].Rows[0]["itemChBy"]);
    return string.Empty;
}
```

**my stored procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE bp_selectItem
(
@itemID INT
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT [itemID],
       [itemName],
       [itemLocation],
       [itemChBy]
FROM   Item 
WHERE itemSystemType='E'  and itemID=@itemID ORDER BY itemID DESC;

END
```

Unfortunately I am a little bit confused and I do not get any valid response.
It is a big enough issue and I am not sure if I give all the necessary informations..
but any help is welcome!

Comment: Why does `LoadItemNew()` return an empty string? Should it return a `SelectEventDetailsDTO` type?

Comment: What response do you expect?  The code is returning `null`.  I would expect this to even be throwing a `NullReferenceException` inside the controller.  When you debug this, where/how specifically is it failing?

Comment: @David The first fail is coming tin Item.cs with message "There is no row at position 0." alhtough I have a value there..

Comment: @DGibbs My approach is to get back those 4 values(those I declare in DTO). I placed to return an empty string just to run the code for first time. Maybe I am thinking of it in a wrong way

Comment: @GeorgiosDeliandreadis: `"alhtough I have a value there"` - You may *assume* or *believe* that you do, but the runtime isn't *lying* to you.  If there's no row, then there's no row.  The stored procedure didn't return any records, it returned an empty set.  So there are multiple problems here.  One is that you're not returning anything from the API call, and the other is that at least in this case there isn't anything to return anyway.  No records were found for the given `ItemID`.

Comment: @GeorgiosDeliandreadis: It's also worth noting that the stored procedure you're showing us and the stored procedure you're calling are not the same thing.

Comment: `bp_selectItem` vs. `sp_lightItem`

Comment: @David Firstly, you are right about the "bp_selectItem vs. sp_lightItem"- that was left from previous changes.. I do not "assume" that I have values, I am pretty sure instead.. And this is becuase I exec the procedure in a query (SQL Manager) and I do have records with the given itemID

Comment: @GeorgiosDeliandreadis: Which procedure did you execute to confirm that?  The one you're showing us, or the one you're using in the code?  Either way, you can be as absolutely sure of your assumptions as you want, but the query isn't returning any results.  I don't deny that you have evidence to suggest what you claim, but the evidence against it (the error message you're getting) is *pretty convincing*.  Instead of insisting that the runtime must be mistaken (which it isn't), debug to determine the inconsistency.

Comment: @David i'll be in touch

Comment: @GeorgeD If you don't need to return anything then you should use `void`.

Comment: @DGibbs I have to return the values in front-end(my next step)

Comment: @GeorgeD Well then return the model and not an empty string?